# How do I set the color of points (lineTo)

Tags: html, colors, settings

I want to change the color of my line at a certain pointer after drawing it.
I set the `strokeStyle` to blue at first, and at later point to green.
However, the whole line gets displayed in green. Is there a way to change the color of the line while it is drawn?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';  // set color to blue
ctx.lineWidth = 1; 
// HOWEVER IT DRAWS IN GREEN - Why ?
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
ctx.lineTo(70,100);
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(50,51);


ctx.moveTo(53,50);
ctx.lineTo(53,51);
ctx.stroke();
// Above color should be Blue  
// Now set the color to green 
ctx.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';

ctx.moveTo(50,53);
ctx.lineTo(50,54);

ctx.moveTo(53,53);
ctx.lineTo(53,54);


ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#myCanvas {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Example 2  Two Lines and a dot.</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). There is a reason that the interface was telling you more details were needed.

Answer (score 0):

You added `ctx.beginPath();` too early. You will also need to add it a second time after changing the color to green.

See this example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';  // set color to blue
ctx.lineWidth = 1; 
//add beginPath() here:
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
ctx.lineTo(70,100);
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(50,51);
ctx.moveTo(53,50);
ctx.lineTo(53,51);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
//again, add beginPath() to make the new dots green:
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,53);
ctx.lineTo(50,54);
ctx.moveTo(53,53);
ctx.lineTo(53,54);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Example 2  Two Lines and a dot.</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></div>
```